# How to upgrade GNOME in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, upgrade

I'm currently using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Gnome 3.36.8. But I like the new GNOME 40 look. I've been using this system for almost 2 years, and I've many programs installed here and everything set up the way I want to. So, is there a way to upgrade my GNOME to the new version?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried this method? https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/04/how-to-install-gnome-40-on-ubuntu-2104.html

Answer (score 7):

Unless you can compile Gnome 40 yourself to run on Ubuntu 20.04, you cannot currently install Gnome 40 on Ubuntu LTS because no PPA exists for this. There is, however, [a PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eshemgp/+archive/ubuntu/gnome-40) that allows to install Gnome 40 on the latest Ubuntu 21.04. So if you want Gnome 40, move to Ubuntu 21.04 first.

Comment: thank you for the information. I did not know that. I will look in it

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to install GNOME 40 on Ubuntu 20.04. I followed these steps and they worked for me.

**Note:** All packages are still in the experimental phase. Installing the repositories mentioned below may break your system.

Instructions:

1. Install the `devacom/gnome-40` and `devacom/x11` repositories to fix `gnome-shell` dependencies:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:devacom/gnome-40
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:devacom/x11
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Install `gnome-shell` before the upgrade (fix desktop will not load):

   ```
   sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
   ```

   - You may also want to install the [Applications Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6/applications-menu/) or [ArcMenu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3628/arcmenu/) extensions using your browser.
3. Upgrade your system:

   ```
   sudo apt upgrade
   ```
4. Reboot your system and enjoy.